# How to pass request parameter via h:commandLink

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing, commandlink, http-request-parameters

I have two forms in my xhtml page, the first includes a commandLink which calls a ManagedBean method :

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <h:commandLink action="#{gestionSessionBean.allerAuSecondMur}">
        <p><h:graphicImage library="default" name="#{gestionSessionBean.logoSecondMur}" id="LogoEcole" /></p>
        <p>Mur <h:outputText value="#{gestionSessionBean.nomSecondMur}"/></p>
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Here is the method:

```
public String allerAuSecondMur() {

    if(id_mur == 1) {
        return "/resources/restreint/Mur.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&id_mur=" + ecole.getId();
    } else {
        return "/resources/restreint/Mur.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&id_mur=1";
    }
}
```

the second has a commandButton :

```
 <h:commandButton class="btn btn-primary btn-sm col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-1" value="Partager" id="BoutonPartager"  action="#{gestionSessionBean.sauvgarderSujet}" />
```

for the method:

```
public void sauvgarderSujet() {

   // business stuff
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Fine");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,message);
}
```

when i click the button it works fine ( i have a global message with an info class and the word Fine show after clicking the button)  but when  i click the commanLink the action is not called in fact it redirect me to the page:
http://localhost:8080/project_name/resources/restreint/Mur.xhtml without the request parameter.

Then i face a HTTP Status 500:java.lang.NumberFormatException: null **due to a filter in my application that required a request parameter and where the filter is not there everything work fine !!**

Here is the only filter, note that ConnexionUtilisateurBean is a SessionScoped Bean

```
  public static final String CONNEXION_UTILISATEUR_BEAN =   "connexionUtilisateurBean";
  public static final String PAGE_ACCUEIL = "/resources/accueil.xhtml";
  public static final String MUR = "/resources/restreint/Mur.xhtml?id_mur=";

 @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    UtilisateurDao utilisateurDao = new UtilisateurDao();

    ConnexionUtilisateurBean connexionUtilisateurBean = (ConnexionUtilisateurBean) session.getAttribute(CONNEXION_UTILISATEUR_BEAN);

    Utilisateur utilisateur = connexionUtilisateurBean.getUtilisateur();

    String paramIdMur = request.getParameter("id_mur");
    int paramTdMurInteger = Integer.parseInt(paramIdMur);
    int idEcoleUtilisateur = utilisateur.getEcole().getId();

    boolean problemeAuNiveauIdentifiantMur = (paramTdMurInteger != 1) && paramTdMurInteger != idEcoleUtilisateur;

    if (utilisateurDao.evaluerExistenceUtilisateur(utilisateur.getEmail()) == null) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + PAGE_ACCUEIL);
    } else if (problemeAuNiveauIdentifiantMur) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + MUR + 1);
    } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
FROM OP's comments:

> I think the filter block the request as i mentioned when the filter is not there everything work fine but i don't know why !!

Comment: without the action being called it is hard to believe it is redirecting to Mur.xhtml. Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked apply to any of your scenario?

Comment: I think the filter block the request as i mentioned when the filter is not there everything work fine but i don't know why !!..the HTTP Status 500:java.lang.NumberFormatException: null  is due to the abscence of request parameter "id_mur" which is strange since it's there in the redirection url !!

Comment: Is there any reason setting `prependId` to `false`? Put an `stdout` statement inside the `allerAuSecondMur()` method to see whether it is invoked properly or not. Check whether the only condition in that method is evaluated to a right boolean value or not and the presence of `ecole.getId()`.

Comment: The reason for setting prepenId to false is for styling the h:graphicImage using the giving id (in other word avoiding the jsf generated id)...the ecole.getId() is there and i don't see how can i check if the method is invoked by using stdout !! could you clarify please..

Comment: Can you add your filter code in the question, please?

Comment: `public String allerAuSecondMur() { System.out.println("allerAuSecondMur() invoked." + " : ecole.getId() = " + ecole.getId() + " : (id_mur == 1) = " + (id_mur == 1)); ...}`.

Comment: NumberFormatException could be there because paramidMur is null or empty or doesnt represent a number here --> `String paramIdMur = request.getParameter("id_mur");
    int paramTdMurInteger = Integer.parseInt(paramIdMur);` Your filter is missing a lot of sanity checks.

Comment: Yup and i want to figure out why as you can see when the commanLink is clicked i set the request parameter "id_mur" so why it's not there and if we assume that the action is not called again what is the matter specially that when i put off the filter everything work fine !!..Thanks and i hope we will find a solution

Comment: I do ***not*** see you passing request parameter in your commandLink. Read http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/ and use step 2 to pass request parameters. Because you are not passing the request parameter properly in commandLink there is a NumberFormatException in the filter and so it works without the filter.

Comment: return "/resources/restreint/Mur.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&id_mur=1"; >>>> the portion &id_mur=1 should pass a request parameter which name is "id_mur" and value 1 ?!

Comment: @Tiny where should i see the output with stdout ?! i'm using intellijidea 14 and can't see any output in the server console !..thank you for your help

Comment: It is displayed on the server terminal (server log) that you see, when you start the server you use.

Comment: Ok i will check it out..thank you

Comment: OP: 'return "/resources/restreint/Mur.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&id_mur=1" is in action. the filter comes in before that and you yourself told the action is not called. @Tiny I want the OP to understand ***passing parameter*** and not take in the scopes used by Mr.Yong.

Comment: @Mahendran Ayyarsamy Kandiar Wich url the filter is dealing with before calling the ManagedBean action ?!

Comment: @Mahendran Ayyarsamy Kandiar thank you very very much the problem is solved and yes i needed to pass the parameter in the url... But i steal have a question in fact the url of the view that contain the commandLink i .../resources/restreint/Mur.xhtml?id_mur=1 so is the filter deal with just http://localhost:8080/project_name/resources/restreint/Mur.xhtml  ???

Comment: @A.Chakroun when u click on a commandLink or commandButton action a POST request is sent and a filter is called. I will add this as solution. If you want you can click on green tick mark below down triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP had issues whenever his filter was *enabled*. A java.lang.NumberFormatException exception was thrown whenever he did so.

Closer inspection of the filter revealed a possible NumberFormatException when request param was null or empty or was not numeric.

FILTER:

```
String paramIdMur = request.getParameter("id_mur");
int paramTdMurInteger = Integer.parseInt(paramIdMur);
int idEcoleUtilisateur = utilisateur.getEcole().getId();
```

OP assumed that this param could not be null as he is passing parameters in action

ACTION:

```
public String allerAuSecondMur() {

if(id_mur == 1) {
    return "/resources/restreint/Mur.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&id_mur=" + ecole.getId();
} else {
    return "/resources/restreint/Mur.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&id_mur=1";
}
```

}

But every action is a POST request and the filter kicks in for his urlPatterns.

So OP needed to pass the request param as

BEGIN EDIT:

```
<f:param name="id_mur" value="{gestionSessionBean.id_mur}" />
```

END EDIT
in his offending commandLink for the Filter to receive this parameter.

Comment: value="{gestionSessionBean.id_mur}"